# Unwrapping result of ApplyTo in ODataQueryOptions

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odata

I have the following function what gets ODataQueryOptions from a Controller. It should get all the Houseentities from Entity Framework and return them. This does work with "/odata/Houses" but "/odata/Houses?$expand=Persons" what should also output all the Persons living in a House does not work.

This is because "expand" changes what the applyTo-Function returns. It seems to get "wrapped" into a "wrapperobject".

```
    public List<elci.BusinessEntities.House> getHouses(ODataQueryOptions qo)
    {
        YardEntities cx = new YardEntities();
       //... mapper configuration omited ... 
        IQueryable<DataAccessLayer.House> query = qo.ApplyTo(cx.Houses) as IQueryable<DataAccessLayer.House>;

        List<BusinessEntities.House> bhl = Mapper.Map<List<DataAccessLayer.House>, List<BusinessEntities.House>>(query.ToList<DataAccessLayer.House>());
        return bhl;
    }
```

Does somebody know how I can "unwrap" them.

My House-Entity looks like this:

```
public partial class House
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public House()
    {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```